# Python Open foreach

Tags: python

I'm having a problem passing the data from `open('C:\\Users\\joerod\\Desktop\\hosts.txt', 'r')` When I run the below script it fails but if I add a `print computer` under the `for computer in hostname:` I see the contents of the file.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import wmi
import paramiko

with open('C:\\Users\\joerod\\Desktop\\hosts.txt', 'r') as hostname:

 for computer in hostname:
    try:
        #gets OS version on Linux boxes
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(computer, username='joerod', password='password')
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cat /etc/redhat-release')
        OS = stdout.readlines()
        print computer, "-", ''.join([item.rstrip('\n') for item in OS])


    except:
           #gets OS version on Windows boxes
           c = wmi.WMI(computer)
           for win in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
             print computer, '-', win.Caption
```

Comment: how does it fail? what would make it succeed?

Comment: `try:` with a bare `except:` is always a bad idea. Using it for your primary logic is an even worse idea. What exception are you actually hoping to catch there?

Comment: @Caprooja: iterating over an open file object yields the lines. Your suggestion would give each character in the file as `computer`.

Comment: @Caprooja, For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code. ref:https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: the logic is check if its linux if I cant ssh it must be windows. still pretty new to python so bear with me

Comment: Python gets better and better the more i learn - nice trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "computer" string is mot likely getting read with a newline/other wrhite sapce bundled - and this is unsuitable as a parameter to Paramiko.

Try simple updating the pramiko call to:

```
client.connect(computer.strip(), username='joerod', password='password')
```